# Any fix for Error: binary ">>" no operator found

Tags: c++

I keep getting

> binary ">>" no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type "type" (or there is no acceptable conversion) or error code C2679.

I tried adding `#include <string>` which also didn't work for me.

Here is the code I have any help would be appreciated

```
#include<iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << setprecision(2) << fixed;
    string fname, sname, tname;
    float bill, tip;
    cout << "Enter first friend name: ";
    cin >> fname;
    cout << "\nEnter second friend name: ";
    cin >> sname;
    cout << "\nEnter third friend name: ";
    cin >> tname;
    cout << "\nEnter amount of bill: $";
    cin >> bill;
    tip = 0.15*bill;
    cout << "\n\nTip amount:\t$" << tip;
    cout << "\nTotal bill:\t$" << tip + bill;
    cout << "\n\n" << fname << ":\t$" << (tip + bill) / 3;
    cout << "\n" << sname << ":\t$" << (tip + bill) / 3;
    cout << "\n" << tname << ":\t$" << (tip + bill) / 3;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code [compiles fine](https://www.ideone.com/roQrVM). What's the problem?

Answer (score 3):

You are missing an include file.

```
#include <string>
```